# Need Very Basic Javascript Form Validation for Name and Email Field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate few fields in my form, I dont want to change anything becasue everything is link to each other and I dont want to mess anything. Basically all I want is to validate name and email field and Once successful then I will move to other fields. I try to do it with below javascript code but it didnt work for me.

NOTE: I need to do it with **Javascript not Jquery**, and I need a **basic Javascript** not **complicated** because I am completely **Novice** to Javascript. ANy help will be appreciated.

[This Is Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/8qsLvx54/)

```js
 var frmvalidator = new Validator("form1");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","req","Please enter your First Name");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("FirstName","maxlen=20",
        "Max length for FirstName is 20");
 
 frmvalidator.addValidation("LastName","req");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("LastName","maxlen=20");
 
 frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","maxlen=50");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","req");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("Email","email");
```

```html
<h1> Contact Form</h1>
   <form id="form1" class="campus"  method="post">
    <div class="form_description">
     <h2>User Feedbacks</h2>
     <p>Please give us your feedbacks.</p>
    </div> 
    
    <ul>
     <li>
      <label class="description" >Name*</label>
     
      <input type="text" name="FullName" id="FirstName" maxlength="50" size="8" />
      <label for="FirstName"> First </label>
      
      <input type="text" name= "user" id="LastName"  maxlength="50" size="8"/>
      <label for="LastName"> Last </label>
     </li>  
   
     <li >
      <label for="Email" class="description">Email*:</label>
      <input type="email" name="Email"  id="Email" maxlength="55"/>
     </li> 
    
     <li>
      <label class="description" >Reason for Contacting:</label>
    
      <input name="choice" id="Hospitality" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
      <label  for="Hospitality">  About Website </label>
      <input name="choice" id="Technology" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="Technology"> About Deals </label>
      <p class="guidelines" ><small>Reason for contacting. Please select all that are applicable</small></p> 
     </li> 
               <li>
       <label class="description" >Will you Recommend us to anyone.</label>
      <select> 
        <option value="" ></option>
        <option value="1" >Yes</option>
        <option value="2" >No</option>
        <option value="3" >Maybe</option>
        </select>
     </li>
     <li>
      <label for="AnyQuestions" class="description" >Any Questions Or Suggessions </label>
      
         <textarea name="AnyQuestions" id="AnyQuestions" class="element textarea large"></textarea> 
     </li>

     <li>
      <label class="description" >Do You want to receive special offers. Please Select One</label>
      <input type="radio" name="opinion" value="1" />
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input  type="radio" name="opinion" value="2" />
      <label> No </label>
     </li>
  
     <li class="buttons">
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
     </li>
    </ul>
   </form>
```

Comment: new Validator("form1"); is not pure Javascript, did you copy it from somewhere ? If so, you will have to import the javascript files where this class is defined.

Comment: I got it from somewhere but they didnt mention anything about javascript files, thats why i am strugling.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the definition of the "Validator" class :

```
function Validator(frmname, alertMethod) {.....}
```

Here is a working Validator class copied on top of your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/8qsLvx54/1/

the code is from http://www.rockcliffepark.com/rp/CONTACT_validator.js (from a google search), you may want to try to find the origin of this code…

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I am trying to figure it out because your answer is little complicated for me. I am looking for very basic Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not come with `Validator` functions that help validate a form.
Instead you could build one or download one like you would jQuery, these extra pieces of code are called Libraries.

Right now the browser does not understand what `Validator` is, so it results in an error. But if you include something like [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) or [Verify.js](http://verifyjs.com/) and write some code according to their documentation you can archive the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without hiding the complexity away in a JavaScript library or framework, you won't get a simple (as in, short) JavaScript solution for what you want. But how about a no-JavaScript solution? [Most of what you want can be done with plain HTML5](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/).

You've already had the `maxlength` attribute in use, just set to different values than what you tried to validate in Javascript. Set them to `20` for the name parts and to `50` for the email address and users won't even be able to enter more characters.

```
<input type="text" name="FullName" id="FirstName" maxlength="20" size="8"/>
```

Add the `required` attribute and any *modern* browser will highlight if they've entered something that doesn't match the `type` attribute's value.

```
<input type="text" name="FullName" id="FirstName" maxlength="20" size="8" required/>
```

For the email field you've already used `type="email"` so you're almost all set just add `required` there, too.

```
<input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" maxlength="50" required/>
```

**Please note** that what is considered to constitute a valid email address differs from browser to browser. (See http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/ section *'INPUT type="email"'*)

To get some custom error message, [you can set the `title` attribute](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/#toc-declarative-error-messages):

```
<input type="text" name="FullName" id="FirstName" maxlength="20" size="8" title="Please enter your First Name (20 characters max.)" required />
```

(Doesn't work in the StackOverflow snippet, don't know why exactly.)

```html
<h1> Contact Form</h1>
<form id="form1" class="campus" method="post">
  <div class="form_description">
    <h2>User Feedbacks</h2>
    <p>Please give us your feedbacks.</p>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <label class="description">Name*</label>

      <input type="text" name="FullName" id="FirstName" maxlength="20" size="8" title="Please enter your First Name (20 characters max.)" required />
      <label for="FirstName">First</label>

      <input type="text" name="user" id="LastName" maxlength="20" size="8" required />
      <label for="LastName">Last</label>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label for="Email" class="description">Email*:</label>
      <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" maxlength="50" required />
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="description">Reason for Contacting:</label>

      <input name="choice" id="Hospitality" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="Hospitality">About Website</label>
      <input name="choice" id="Technology" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="Technology">About Deals</label>
      <p class="guidelines"><small>Reason for contacting. Please select all that are applicable</small>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="description">Will you Recommend us to anyone.</label>
      <select>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="2">No</option>
        <option value="3">Maybe</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="AnyQuestions" class="description">Any Questions Or Suggessions</label>

      <textarea name="AnyQuestions" id="AnyQuestions" class="element textarea large"></textarea>
    </li>

    <li>
      <label class="description">Do You want to receive special offers. Please Select One</label>
      <input type="radio" name="opinion" value="1" />
      <label>Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="opinion" value="2" />
      <label>No</label>
    </li>

    <li class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I have done HTml validation before, However I need to do javasxript validation this time, Only for name and email field just to start. I have viewed many sources but If I use their code then I need to change my form code which I dont want because Css and other functions are link together and I dont want to mess anything.....Thanks for your comments anyway but just need javascript validation.